# Adding checkbox to EditText like in the Evernote app

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-formatting

I'm currently developing a note taking app. One of the requests for the app is to be able to put checkboxes (clickable, checkable) anywhere into the text like Evernote allows.

[image: Illustration image]

I know you cannot simply just put Views into the EditText widget. Also, the solution has to be able to serialize into a database and able to be loaded to the same formatting as it was left.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in normal EditText? I welcome every idea that might lead to a solution.

Comment: Is it a real CheckBox? 'cause you can maybe use a special char (like a emoji)? and if the user click on it you change the 'emoji' for the checked/unchecked version? https://emojipedia.org/ballot-box-with-check/

Comment: I think it is, because it has material design ripple effect when you  click it, but can't say for sure. On the other hand you might just found kinda cool trick how to do that, thank you for this, very appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [rich editor](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) library? It has a ton of functionality, including checkboxes inside `EditText`. I guess this one is exactly what you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the CheckBox view available with android?

```xml
<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkbox_item"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:checked="false"
     android:onClick="changeCheckboxState"
     android:text="Task 1" />
```

Implement the `changeCheckboxState()` method in your code to change checked state by using `checkbox.setChecked(true)` which will achieve what you want -

[image]

This way you can create a ListView/RecyclerView and attach this checkbox item to a custom adapter and keep a track of the state of the checkbox in you database

Further if you want to customise the look of your checkbox to resemble Evernote you can put it in a Linear Layout with other buttons to the right of the text in the checkbox.

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I needed the checkbox to be part of the text and the text had to be one element (edittext). Which cannot be done in  Android.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted then. In that case you can possibly use two image drawables (checked and unchecked) and maintain it's state in the DB as Eselfar already suggested!